# Sequential execution in node.js using arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was learning sequential execution in node.js and came across an interesting problem.

Below is my code. Basically, I have 5 RSS Feeds in an array and I am trying to output titles of them sequentially. For this purpose, I have created an array of functions and utilizing this helper function from a book:

```
function next(err, result)
{
    if(err) throw new Error(err);

    var currentTask = tasks.shift();

    if(currentTask)
    {
        currentTask(result);
    }

}
```

Now, my program works correctly, If I prepare array as :

```
tasks = [

function(){handle(urls[0])},
function(){handle(urls[1])},
function(){handle(urls[2])},
function(){handle(urls[3])},
function(){handle(urls[4])}

];
```

However it outputs in random order and not sequential, if I prepare as:

```
tasks = [

handle(urls[0]),
handle(urls[1]),
handle(urls[2]),
handle(urls[3]),
handle(urls[3]),

];
```

What is the difference between above 2 arrays?

Full Code:

```
var request = require('request');
var parser = require('htmlparser');

var urls = ['http://psychcentral.com/blog/feed/rss2/', 'http://davidicuswong.wordpress.com/feed/', 'http://www.theglobalconversation.com/blog/?feed=rss2', 'http://happiness-project.com/feed', 'http://www.marriagemissions.com/feed/'];

function handle(url)
{
    request(url, function(error, response, body)
    {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
        {
            var handler = new parser.RssHandler();
            var rssParser = new parser.Parser(handler);

            rssParser.parseComplete(body);

            if (handler.dom.items.length)
            {
                var item = handler.dom.items.shift();
                console.log(item.title);
                console.log(item.link);
            }

           next(null, null);
        }


    });

}

function next(err, result)
{
    if(err) throw new Error(err);

    var currentTask = tasks.shift();

    if(currentTask)
    {
        currentTask(result);
    }

}


tasks = [

function(){handle(urls[0])},
function(){handle(urls[1])},
function(){handle(urls[2])},
function(){handle(urls[3])},
function(){handle(urls[4])}

];

next();
```

Comment: Well, the first is an array of functions, while the second is an array of `undefined`s?

Comment: Yes I agree, but how come it still executes and outputs in random order though...

Comment: Well, *you* are executing it (not the `next()` queue), and they execute in parallel.

Comment: aah, I see ... it was so simple .. but I missed .. Thanks

Comment: You can put this as an answer.. I will be glad to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between above 2 arrays?

Well, the first is an array of functions, while the second is an array of `undefined`s.

> but how come it still executes and outputs in random order though?

*You* are executing it (not the `next()` queue), and they execute in parallel, so the async callbacks come back in non-deterministic order.